# Variable Struct for JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, variables, struct

Hello Im using JSON in my script in this way:

```
//Top of Script

struct Runway: Decodable {
let ident1: String }

struct Runways: Decodable {
let runways: [Runway]

init(runways: [Runway]) {
    self.runways = runways
}
}

//Getting Values
let aero4 = try decoder.decode(Runways.self, from: data)
print(aero4.runways.ident1)

{ "runways": [
    {
      "ident1": "13R",
```

So the above prints 13R. Now how can I structure my code so that I can retrieve any json, lets say if user types LA the json would return with first [] as [runwaysLA], so basically the first [] in JSON return is always different and variable to user input? Not quite sure how to use the struct with a variable

```
{ "runwaysLA": [
    {
      "ident1": "13R",
```

or

```
 { "runwaysBA": [
            {
              "ident1": "13C",
```

or

```
 { "runwaysWA": [
            {
              "ident1": "13L",
```

Comment: And to add,I can’t list these 3 in my struct. As that’s just an example, the amount of responses is over 10,000. So I need it to be variable to input.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to eliminate the explicit `Runways` struct and parse directly into a dictionary, like so:

```
struct Runway: Decodable {
    let ident1: String
}

typealias Runways = [String: [Runway]]

do {
    let r = try JSONDecoder().decode(Runways.self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)

    // example: get the first ident from WA, if present
    if let rwa = r["runwaysWA"], !rwa.isEmpty {
        print(rwa[0].ident1)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, didn’t know that would work. And how would I customise the print function to print just the ident part let’s say from str = “runwaysWA”

Comment: Updated my answer with an example

Comment: Thank you! I haven’t parsed this way before, but that’s what I needed!